# Execute Gradle build from deeper folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to execute a gradle build in a subdirectory but it doesn't go any lower than the root build.gradle

To illustrate, I have a root `project` folder, as well as the following

```
project
project/build.gradle
project/api
project/api/build.gradle
project/api/src
project/core
project/core/build.gradle
project/core/src
```

When I click run the `project/api/build.gradle` file, it will build the files, underneath the `project` directory, like

```
project/api/src/package/Class.java
project/target/classes/package/Class.class
```

What I want is to separate the built classes into each subfolder.

```
project/api/src/package/Class.java
project/api/target/classes/package/Class.class
```

Is there a way to specify in eclipse to use the sub folder as the project folder? I can run gradle either by `cd`ing into the directory, or using the `-p` argument on the command line, but can't seem to find a way to do this with eclipse.

The only thing that I haven't tried yet, is to have a task `buildApi` and `buildCore` in the `project/build.gradle` file and then set the output folder there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple Gradle build files, you need to setup [multi-project builds](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).